# Hot brown on brown action in /review

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image: The review page with the suggested edits counter.]

The suggested edits counter in the Review page features a `.hotbg` brown on `.mod-flag-indicator` brown counter.

Can it be made more readable?

Comment: I'm looking into this now. btw, totally misleading question title.

Comment: @Grace I figured that if Jin wants to put a test suggested edit, he can do so in an incognito window.

Comment: [Clicked link.  Was disappointed.](http://abstrusegoose.com/strips/rooster_of_unusual_size.PNG)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

February 18, hmm? I guess it took us 4.5 to 6 times 6 to 8 weeks to fix this.

Comment: When I looked at my screenshot I wondered what the hell that splotch of red by my nickname was. (I take it the change is yet to be deployed?)

Comment: Yep; I figured that you've lived with this for nine months, so an immediate build wasn't that important.

Comment: It was fixed for a bit, but now it's back to unreadable for me.

Comment: @balpha As lunboks said, this change appears to have been rolled back. Possibly with the double tag change.

Comment: @lunboks: yeah, when the skyrim vs. mw3 theme was removed, my fix was accidentally reverted. Refixed in the next build.

Comment: @DoozerBlake: see above

Comment: oops yes it was caused by the Skyrim vs MW3 theme changed.